# Ubuntu 16.04 Certificate Authority Not Iniating - OpenSSL

Tags: xubuntu, ssl, landscape, openssl, syslinux

I am attempting to generate and sign a new SSL certificate as the previous one was issued to a different domain name and is preventing login to landscape from the web. Although I am running into a strange problem in that the command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newca
```

Simply continues to the next blank line within the Linux shell and doesn't continue to the next step in creating the certificate authority... This was working 30 minutes ago, and the command below to generate the SSL certificate functions as expected.

```
sudo /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newreq-      nodes
```

More information as to what it is that I am trying to do:

https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL

Answer (score 2):

Your first command establishes yourself as a certificate authority for a period of time, usually one year.  Running it a second time, 30 minutes later is unnecessary and could well be causing you problems.

Once you have declared yourself to be a CA you can create as many SSL certificates as you like.  It's not clear from your posting if this is still working.  If it is, you're fine.

I don't see anything in the man page about revoking a CA authority.  If trying to create two CAs 30 minutes apart broke something you may have to manually delete the pem file(s)